# How do I use com.google.firebase.database classes in a Java (not Android) library?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an Android Studio project in which I have three modules:

- `app`: An Android app
- `model`: A Java library containing my POJOs that get persisted to Firebase Database
- `service`: An App Engine web application with a servlet that persists some stuff to Firebase Database

Both the `service` and the `app` modules depend on the `model` module. The `model` module doesn't depend on either the `app` or the `service`.

The `model` module contains only POJOs, but I've just found myself needing to use the `com.google.firebase.database.Exclude` annotation in order to prevent a field from being written to the database. As soon as I add a compile dependency to either the Firebase admin or the Firebase server SDK to my `module` project and rebuild, my app crashes before it gets as far as logging anything.

I've tried using these dependencies in the `model` module (one at a time, not both at once):

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:4.0.3'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:3.0.1'
```

My guess is that they're both pulling in a bunch of stuff that doesn't belong in an Android app. I've also tried:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
```

But that gives me a gradle error:

```
Error:Module 'biketracker-android-service:model:unspecified' depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar
```

Is there a library I can use that gives me just the bare minimum Firebase Database classes and is not an Android library?

Comment: Wouldn't adding that dependency couple your model objects to the database layer? If you are really wanting to separate your modules, I don't think you're going to be able to get just that annotation class.

Comment: Yes, by doing this I'm making my model module Firebase Database-specific, but I can live with that I think. I'd prefer that to making it Android-specific and then using it on the server, or server SDK-specific  and then using it in the Android app.

Comment: I guess, there is this one. Shouldn't be Android specific. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-admin. Although, you already have tried that

Comment: I appears firebase uses the public getter methods to retrieve the values, it may be possible to import the jar, extend the model needed, override and '@Exclude' the getter on the app side or within an Android library.

Comment: @DaveS That's an option I guess. Leaves me with some model code in all three modules though. And duplication of code in the app and service modules, potentially.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of an Android library for the app and service modules that did this while preserving the jar for usage away from it.